# fetching data in calendarkit from json file

Tags: swift, calendarkit

```
override func eventsForDate(_ date: Date) -> [EventDescriptor] {
      var models = Model.shared.appoinmentProfessional
        for model in models{
            // Create new EventView
            let event = Event()
            // Specify StartDate and EndDate
            event.startDate = model.startDate
            event.endDate = model.endDate
            // Add info: event title, subtitle, location to the array of Strings
            var info = [model.title, model.location]
            info.append("\(datePeriod.beginning!.format(with: "HH:mm")) - \(datePeriod.end!.format(with: "HH:mm"))")
            // Set "text" value of event by formatting all the information needed for display
            event.text = info.reduce("", {$0 + $1 + "\n"})
            events.append(event)
        }
        return events

    }
```

I am new to swift and don't how to do fetch data in calendarkit for dynamic events from json file .I have done everything whatever I could do but nothing worked for me.

I am new to mvc pattern so any please guide me how to fetch data from son using model in calendarkit file